# Chromium with GUI running in docker container

Tags: docker, chromium, xserver

I want to run Chromium browser inside docker container. So the first step for me would be just to manage to start startx inside container.
Now I managed to make service which is just:
startx

Now when I start Virtual Machine with base ubuntu it opens startx GUI and I can manipulate it (use it's gui, open browser etc.).
After that I added .xinitrc with chromium-browser --kiosk inside it to open browser in kiosk mode, added Xwrapper.config inside /etc/X11/ and export DISPLAY=:0 and works perfectly fine. So the wanted behavior is when I boot my VM I want to open chromium browser directly without doing any manipulation on connected screen to VM.

Is the same what I did with systemd service and .xinitrc possible with docker container with base ubuntu image?

For now what I tried is following:
Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    xfce4-session \
    xfce4-goodies \
    xinit \
    snap \
    snapd \
    chromium-browser

# Set the default command to startx
CMD ["startx"]
```

So when I start container with:

```
docker run --rm --privileged -it --net=host my-chromium-image
```

Container runs, gui starts and gets stuck and frozen and I cannot do anything.

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process; it doesn't run any sort of system services or daemons.  Further, because it's isolated, it can't usually access the host display or hardware devices, or the user's home directory.  Is there a specific reason you want this inside a container?  Would a virtual machine running an out-of-the-box desktop Linux distribution be easier to set up?